# Open link in window that contains iframe where link is initiated

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have an iframe that contains a webpage I built. I have a link in that I frame, and when I click on the link it opens up the link within the iframe. How do I make it so that the link opens in my main window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all links in your iframe to open into the parent frame, add the following tag to the head of your html document:

```
<base target="_parent">
```

([See documentation for `base` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base).)

Otherwise, just add a `target="_parent"` attribute to the link you want opened in the parent frame. ([See documentation for `target` attribute of `a` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).)

In either case, if there is no parent frame/context, `_parent` behaves like `_self`.